# For loop displaying the same row

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to push an excel row to an array.

So the way I have it is, I use a foreach loop to loop through the excel file and then I use a for loop that
loops through and checks the value for me and does some validation.

The problem I'm having is that in my for loop I'm getting the first row of my excel file and it prints out mulitple times and
what I should be getting is all the rows that was successful.

Here is my code

```
    $col = $sheet->getHighestDataColumn();
    $row = $sheet->getHighestDataRow();
    $rowCount = $sheet->getHighestDataRow();
    $allRows = $sheet->rangeToArray("A1:{$col}{$row}", null, false);

    $arr = [];

    foreach($allRows as $row)
    {
        for($x = 0; $x <= $rowCount; $x++)
        {
            if($x == 0 || $x == 1) continue;

            $col1 = $sheet->getCell("D$x")->getValue();
            $col2 = $sheet->getCell("E$x")->getValue();
            $col3 = $sheet->getCell("F$x")->getValue();
            $col4 = $sheet->getCell("G$x")->getValue();
            $total = $sheet->getCell("H$x")->getValue();

            $testTotal = $col1 + $col2 + $col3 + $col4;
            if($testTotal === $total)
            {
                echo "<PRE>";
                echo print_r($row);
                echo "</PRE>";
        
                $arr[] = $row;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the first row printed multiple times because you are printing it within a for loop which itself is within a foreach loop.

You don't need to do the validation within the foreach loop because the validation doesn't use $row.

Do the validation outside and then proceed to use the $allRows

```php
$col = $sheet->getHighestDataColumn();
$row = $sheet->getHighestDataRow();
$rowCount = $sheet->getHighestDataRow();
$allRows = $sheet->rangeToArray("A1:{$col}{$row}", null, false);

$validatedRowCount = 0;

//Do the validation
for($x = 0; $x <= $rowCount; $x++)
{
    if($x == 0 || $x == 1) continue;

    $col1 = $sheet->getCell("D$x")->getValue();
    $col2 = $sheet->getCell("E$x")->getValue();
    $col3 = $sheet->getCell("F$x")->getValue();
    $col4 = $sheet->getCell("G$x")->getValue();
    $total = $sheet->getCell("H$x")->getValue();

    $testTotal = $col1 + $col2 + $col3 + $col4;

    $validatedRowCount = $testTotal === $total 
        ? $validatedRowCount + 1 
        : $validatedRowCount;            
}

if($validatedRowCount === $rowCount) {
//Safe to assume that $allRows contains validated data
//Proceed to use $allRows
}
```

Or if you want to validate each row and filter each individual row via validation then

```php
$col = $sheet->getHighestDataColumn();
$row = $sheet->getHighestDataRow();
$rowCount = $sheet->getHighestDataRow();
$allRows = $sheet->rangeToArray("A1:{$col}{$row}", null, false);

$validatedRows = [];

foreach($allRows as $index => $row)
{
    $col1 = $sheet->getCell("D$index")->getValue();
    $col2 = $sheet->getCell("E$index")->getValue();
    $col3 = $sheet->getCell("F$index")->getValue();
    $col4 = $sheet->getCell("G$index")->getValue();
    $total = $sheet->getCell("H$index")->getValue();

    $testTotal = $col1 + $col2 + $col3 + $col4;

    if($testTotal === $total) {
         echo "<PRE>";
         echo print_r($row);
         echo "</PRE>";
        $validatedRows[] = $row;
    }
}
```